Unable to create new line in text in Inksape Vector
I am using Inkscape version 1.3.2
When I try to press enter after a line of text, it doesn't create a new paragraph and instead writes in the same line as the previous text.
The spacing between baselines is set to 1.0 which is normal and I haven't been able to find a solution for this anywhere other than like pressing Enter a hundred times just to get the line under the previous one.

Hi. I can't reproduce this problem. It seems to be working just fine.  You might want to try resetting the preferences.  Do Edit > Preferences > System and hit the Reset Preferences button.

Also, when you say "baseline", You say it is set to 1, but is that 1 "line"?  Check the units.

Okay, problem solved! Thank you Billy Kerr for bringing the units to my attention, apparently the unit was set to pt and when I converted it to lines it was 0,03 lines.
Changed the unit to lines and set it then to 1, all is well!
